# Unity 2d mobile button c# script is not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, mobile

I want to know how to do something on a touch.
Please write any script example or what to do.

```cs
public Transform MoveThis;
public GameObject Here;

void OnClick() => MoveThis.transform.position = Here.transform.position;
```

I watched a lot of youtube videos and I tried a lot of scripts but it seems none worked for me.

Comment: You want to handle just any touch on the screen or you want to handle the click of a specific button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unity documentation is a fount of knowledge, including a page for the [IPointerClick interface](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html).

On that page there is the small example:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    //Detect if a click occurs
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        //Output to console the clicked GameObject's name and the following message. You can replace this with your own actions for when clicking the GameObject.
        Debug.Log(name + " Game Object Clicked!");
    }
}
```

One thing to take particular note of is this instruction:

> Ensure an Event System exists in the Scene to allow click detection.